# What is the difference between (string&)string() and (string&)"" as a default parameter?

Tags: c++, ofstream, default-parameters

I declare a logging function with an info-string as default parameter.

```
void LogError(ErrorEnum error, string& infoStr = (string&)"")
```

When the function is called without the additional string i get an unhandled exception while trying to write into a log stream in such a way:

```
    ofstream mystream;
   //do some stuff
   mystream<< "Error " << infoStr << " failed!" << endl;
```

If ich change the default parameter to (string&)string(), the exception does not occur anymore. Debugging with VS2013 shows that in both cases the value of infoStr is "".

So where is the difference in the between the two declarations?

Comment: Why are you casting to `string&`? Doesn't `string& infoStr = ""` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, you are basically casting from `char const (&) [1]` to `string&`. That is obviously not valid. `std::string` is a class, it is not singleton array of characters, hence the exception. In the second case you are casting a temporary from rvalue to lvalue. That is dubious but since the referenced value is actually of the same type it works out fine.